# InvalidArgumentException - Installing older version of Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to install an older version of laravel it gives me   `[InvalidArgumentException] Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.8.* in a version installable using your PHP version, PHP extensions and Composer version.`

This is my PHP version
$ php --version
`PHP 8.0.0 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2020 22:02:57) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 ) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.0.0-dev, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies`

I used this command to install laravel
`$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.8.*"`

I removed the composer installation and reinstall it again it always gives the same error. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you install Laravel? show us the composer command

Comment: `$ composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog "5.8.*"`

Comment: run `composer -vvv about` and post the output

Comment: It gives 
`Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: C:/Users/pc/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Running 2.0.9 (2021-01-27 16:09:27) with PHP 8.0.0 on Windows NT / 10.0
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: C:/Users/pc/AppData/Roaming/Composer/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described 
`

Comment: the issue with composer installation. are u using wamp or xampp ?? use PHP 7.1 with laravel 5.* versions

Comment: I'm using xampp

Comment: when installing composer did you select correct PHP version ??

Comment: install php 7.1 in xampp and reinstall composer will solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot run Laravel 5.8 on PHP 8.0. Laravel 5.8 requires PHP ^7.1.3.
The only version fully supporting PHP 8.0 to date is Laravel 8.x.

Furthermore, I strongly advise not to use an old Laravel version like that, as it is not actively maintained anymore. Fortunately, upgrading an existing Laravel 5.8 project to Laravel 6 is fairly simple, just head over to https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade and work your way through the upgrade guide.

Laravel 6 is a LTS version and will receive bug fixes until September 7th, 2021 and security fixes until September 6th, 2022.

Upgrading Laravel 6 to 7 and 7 to 8 is even less of an issue than the 5.8 -> 6 update, so you might want to keep going until you are up to date and can stick with PHP 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 5.8 dosent work with PHP 8, downgrade your PHP Version to 7.4 and it should work

Comment: Sure, but this was not his question he want to run Laravel 5.8 maybe doesent work his app with Laravel 8 or some liberys who knows